My TI-84 Plus CE contents refuse to show up in TI connect CE
As stated, the TI connect does not display my calculator contents, only stating "the calculator was busy and could not display it's contents." I have attempted most fixes I could, resetting my calculator, restarting my computer, even my software is up to date, as it was installed yesterday. If you have any idea how to fix this, please help. I have seen something similar online, but it wasn't persistent and resolved after resetting the calculator.

I did that twice now, it hasn't fixed it at all. the same error shows up.

maybe you have pirated software ... the incorrectly spelled it's in the message could be an indicator

i was typing out the message by hand... that was human error.
